# Compiler flags which make reverse engineering harder

Tags: gcc, g++

Recently I read that using specific compiler flags can prevent or make reverse engineering much more complicated. I'm using those flags

```
-s -O3 -Os -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wl,--gc-sections
```

Is it enough protection or maybe i used too many flags?
I'm using `MinGW-W64 x86_64-posix 11.3.0`

Comment: You can't have both `-O3` and `-Os`, the last one wins.

Comment: @ssbssa so basically my compilatior was ignoring that -O3 all the time?

Comment: Yes, see [Optimize Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html): `If you use multiple -O options, with or without level numbers, the last such option is the one that is effective`

Comment: @ssbssa which option generates library which size is smaller?